# trying to check the upload file is json , but even uploading a valid json extension it throwing me an error, what im doing wrong

Tags: javascript

```js
 document.getElementById('uploader').onsubmit = function () {
        var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('browseFile');
        //Iterating through each files selected in fileInput
        for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
            //Appending each file to FormData object
            formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
        }
        if (fileInput.files[0].name.includes("json") == "true") {
            //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sendingsss
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/Dealer/UploadReportSuccess');
            xhr.send(formdata);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    $('#uploader').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#Upload').css('display', 'block');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('please select a valid json file');
           // $('.errorDiv').css('display', 'block');
            return false;
        }
        
    }   

});
```

Comment: I do not see you cancelling the form submission. The form is going to submit causing issues. What is the error?

Comment: Can you fix your snippet so it a) doesn'T throw a syntax error b) reproduces the problem?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: after uploading json file my if condition is not working, its directly going to else and thrwoing an alert

Comment: So did you debug? Did you check the name? `console.log(fileInput.files[0].name, fileInput.files[0].name.includes("json"))`

Comment: Yeah this is what im getting

Comment: VM128:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: fileInput is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (fileInput.files[0].name.includes("json") == true)

changing string to true will works, because includes is bool will not check string to string